# Neo4j @Relationship always returns null

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am always getting null from the annotated @Relationship field (from neo4j ogm). Below is my simplified class implementation.

```
@NodeEntity
public class A {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS") private Set<B> mB;

    public Set<B> getB() {
        return mB;
    }
}

@NodeEntity
public class B {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private A mA;
}
```

This is how I created my graph

```
CREATE (a:A), (b1:B), (b2:B)
CREATE (a)-[:HAS]->(b1), (a)-[:HAS]->(b2)
```

When I called `getB()`, it returned null. I can get all `B` instances from the graph using query as below

```
MATCH (:A)-[:HAS]->(b:B) RETURN b
```

The project was set up by spring-boot with neo4j, and I had those controller, domain, repository and service working. I could do some simple API calls to the server to get those attributes of class A or B (which I did not list above). It was just that I could not get this `mB` value. Any step I missed out to do?

Comment: How do you load the data (`A`)? Could you add this to the question?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Currently stuck on what sounds like the same problem...